# Reference Issue: Can't find variable on iOS but only on heroku

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, marionette

This is for a Backbone + Marionette app.

Here's the offending code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

Gameq.start({
    currentUser: gon.current_user,
    env: gon.environment,
    signed_in: gon.signed_in,
    userSession: gon.user_session 
});

//]]>
</script>
```

Here's the whole document.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gameq</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.gon = {};gon.environment="production";gon.signed_in=true;gon.current_user={"created_at":"2013-11-21T23:53:28Z","email":"mikeborg85@gmail.com","id":1,"name":null,"provider":null,"uid":null,"updated_at":"2013-11-28T22:42:42Z"};gon.user_session={};
//]]>
</script>
    <link href="/assets/application-66c0c36aa2fa6c5e2193b02c1ab6534b.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/overrides-5e3c108b1b6688f22c03c69f670b1925.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/application-86895940b8f231c1d77366a2444fecc5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="bk8ryvwdGqulNZ5Utfu5Q4L3vJ9AjWzYnGgj/H9tMOw=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="global-nav-region" class="navbar"></div>
    <div id="main-region"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="bottom-menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <ul class="bottom-links">
            <li><a href="#fakelink">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fakelink">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fakelink">Support</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <ul class="bottom-icons">
            <li><a class="fui-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/gameqme"></a></li>
            <li><a class="fui-twitter" href="#fakelink"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

Gameq.start({
    currentUser: gon.current_user,
    env: gon.environment,
    signed_in: gon.signed_in,
    userSession: gon.user_session 
});

//]]>
</script>
</html>
```

When I use any desktop browser it works, but when I test in iOS I get a "Reference Issue Can't Find Variable Gameq" error. It works fine in iOS when its hosted on localhost but not when its on heroku.

Why would Heroku cause this problem?

**EDIT:**

I've tried wrapping the offending code in document ready functions.

Comment: Have you tried with `$(document).ready()`? Or maybe `$()`? Have you tested on another server? Heroku version works fine on desktop?

Comment: I've tried with both. I've tested on localhost. It works fine on localhost with both desktop browsers and mobile browsers. It's only on heroku with mobile browsers (iOS and Android so far tested) where I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was indeed only with mobile browsers. Moving the following code into app/assets/javascripts/application.js within the rails application fixed the problem.

```
Gameq.start({
  currentUser: gon.current_user,
  env: gon.environment,
  signed_in: gon.signed_in,
  userSession: gon.user_session 
});
```

I can't really explain what is different about loading within mobile devices that causes this error.